# Is there a CSS property to allow working with current div size?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, size

Is there a CSS property/trick that would allow me to move a div in a certain direction same amount of pixels as current div size ?

For example I don't know div height but I want to move it upper until it goes out of the screen, that would mean `[move it upwards same amount of pixels as box height]`.

I am thinking something like: `margin-bottom: current-height;` or `margin-left: current-width;`

Is there anything like that ?

Comment: `translateY(-100%)`

Comment: You could use `transform`, like `transform: translateY(-100%)`

Comment: Thank you, `translateY` seems to be what I was looking for, I don't know why the down votes thou.